# logstash:how to use environment variables in input host

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I wanna print 'host source' to output. For this goal, local or global variables is necessary. But I wanna not use the global variables like 'export ...'.
So before the input{}, I put the host in metadata then use in 'input{}'.
Like below:

```
filter{
  environment{
    add_field =>{
      "[@metadata][TEMP]" => "127.0.0.1"
       }
    }
  }
input{
  udp{
    host => "%{[@metadata][TEMP]}"
    port => "10000"
    }
  }
output{
  udp{
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    port => "10001"
    }
}
```

But logstash is not running then log is like below:

```
[WARN ][logstash.inputs.udp      ] UDP listener died {:exception=>#<SocketError: bind: name or service not known>known>
```

So how can solve this problem??

Comment: Can you check if your ports are already in use? You can get this information with 'sudo lsof -nPi :10000'

Comment: @ChristianHäckh Thank you for replying. That port is not used because if I set host => "127.0.0.1", then it is work.

Comment: Filters are applied to events AFTER the input. The environment filter can be used to access environment variables and change events accordingly, not to set new environment variables. If you want to use environment variables, you should export them.

Comment: @ChristianHäckh Thank you for replying. I understand your comment. Can I use the host value of udp in 'input{}' to other side like 'filter{}' without environemtn variables ? Because I wanna print the host value of udp in output side. But in 'udp{}' host is not added to field with using 'add_field'.

Comment: Is your host value dynamic or static? If it is static, you could just add a field to the event using a "mutate" filter.

Comment: @ChristianHäckh Thank you for replying. Now I just test the demo, so it is static. But it will be dynamic address.

Comment: For dynamic values, you can try the following "ruby" filter: filter {ruby {init => "require 'socket'" code => "event['some-field-name'] = Socket.gethostname"}}.

Comment: @ChristianHäckh Thank you for replying. After your comment, just put the 'some-field-name' in host?? like input{udp{host =>some-field-name}}} or input{udp{host =>event['some-field-name']}}} or input{udp{host =>event.get['some-field-name']}} ? Three statement is not working.

Comment: I think, I have enough information to address your question. I will sum up our discussion in a seperate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try the answer your question in two steps.

**The error message**
Your config file is malformed. The workflow is always like this:

```
# This is a comment. You should use comments to describe
# parts of your configuration.
input {
  ...
}

filter {
  ...
}

output {
  ...
}
```

That is why you get the error message, your filter is in the wrong place and not applied before the input.

**Multiple input sources**
If you want to add information to your events depending on which input is used, you can add a type during input handling. Here is an example config file:

```
input {
  file {
    type => "file"
    path => "/var/log/some_name.log"
  }
  udp{
    type => "udp"
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    port => "10001"
  }
} 

filter {
  # can be omitted, if not used
}

output {
  udp{
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    port => "10001"
  }
}
```

The type is stored as part of the event itself, so you can also use the type to search for it in Kibana.

Comment: This is not enough for my question. My question is how to use local or environment variable in host value. So you did suggest with using ruby, value including host can be used in field. But this value can not used other side like 'input{}'.